# Run javascript in renderHead with markupId as a parameter in Wicket

Tags: java, wicket

I have a Panel "MainPanel" and component "MyComponent" inside this panel. And I would like to pass the markupId of my component as a parameter in javascript function which will be called in renderHead(). How to do it ?

```
    public MainPanel(String id) {
        super(id);
        MyComponent div = new MyComponent("div");
        div.setmarkupId("customeUniqueId");
        div.add(new AjaxEventBehavior("click") {

            @Override
            protected void onEvent(AjaxRequestTarget target) {

                String markupId = div.getMarkupId();
                target.appendJavaScript("window.location.reload();");
                target.appendJavaScript(jsReload(markupId));

            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
        super.renderHead(response);
        // how to use here div.markupId value as a parameter???
        response.render(OnDomReadyHeaderItem.forScript(String.format("my_js_callback('%s')", div.getMarkupId())));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to add the div to MainPanel: `add(div);`. I guess you already have it in your code but it missing in the shown snippet.

Then you can reach the `div` by using `get("div").getMarkupId()`, i.e. get the child with id "div". Another way is to extract `MyComponent div` as a member field of `MainPanel` class and then just use `div.getMarkupId()`.

Comment: what do you mean with get child with id "div" ? I'm getting error ```get("div").getMarkupId()``` after this call